# How to update textviews when data is updated in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I have a quotes app, and what I do is I store new quotes in excel and then convert them to JSON (as well as the old ones), and then import the json file into Firebase.

Now the problem is when I do this if my app is already running and I request a new quote to display, the total number of quotes (for example 1000) gets confusing. It doesn't display the correct total number unless I completely close my app and then reopen it.

Would you please tell me how to update both texts (1. The total number 2. the textview showing the quotes) with the updated quotes, when an event occurs (e.g., clicking the nav buttons to bring next or previous quotes or like getting on resume)?

Look at [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f4gyMGqFF0SVxiZZwwN25IBAzQpwLx7T/view)

> (the text changed itself to 10001 when i just added one quote in the
> firebase and even the added quote is not displaying when i press the
> latest quote - which get the lastest added quote in firebase)

Im using this right now to get data

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes");
        model = new Model();
        quotes_list = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    if (model != null) {
                        quotes_list.add(model.getTitle());
                        position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                        Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());

                    }
                }
                quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
                countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
                Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());
            }
```

Model

```
package com.example.philosophicalquotes.data;

public class Model {
    String title;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo  Suppose last time there were 500 quotes and then I added 100 more quotes in the excel and converted them to json and uploaded to firebase . Then the totalnumber shows for example 900 instead of 600, even if I navigate between different quotes it still shows the wrong number, so I have to restart the app to see the correct number.

Comment: @AlexMamo Look at this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f4gyMGqFF0SVxiZZwwN25IBAzQpwLx7T/view

Comment: Add your sample firebase json. and addValueEventListener always listenable.. You no need to fetch again. Do you have different methods in your class for reading quotes?
Read this doc first---- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your `onDataChange` is called, it gets a `DataSnapshot` with *all* data at the `Quotes` path in your database. You need to clear the existing data from the `quotes_list` list before rebuilding it.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        quotes_list.clear(); // 
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
            if (model != null) {
                quotes_list.add(model.getTitle());
                position = randomQ.nextInt(quotes_list.size());
                Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());
            }
        }
        quotesTxt.setText(quotes_list.get(position));
        countTxt.setText(position + "/" + quotes_list.size());
        Log.d(TAG, quotes_list.toString());
    }
```